# Can any one please explain which indexes to refresh in magento after mentioned changes

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Which Index need to be refresh after updating any of the changes i do. I don't want to refresh all the indexes.

1. updating products
2. adding new products
3. adding new attributes or attribute values
4. adding new categories
5. updating or adding new static CMS pages or blocks

More questions associated

If we are not changing any attribute data when updating products, do I still need to refresh the "Product Attributes" index?

If we are not changing prices when updating products, do we still need to refresh the "Product Prices" index?

If we are not changing the URLs when updating products (IE: Title Changes, URL redirect changes, etc) do we still need to refresh the "Catalog URL Rewrites" index?

If we are not changing any product categories when updating products, do we still need to refresh the "Category Products" index?

Since we do not use Magento's default search system, do we ever need to refresh the "Catalog Search Index"?  If so under what circumstances?

If we are not changing any product stock statues when updating products, do we still need to refresh the "Stock Statuses" index?

We do not use Product Tags.  Do we ever need to refresh the "Tag Aggregation Data" index?

Comment: You are probably better asking this on [magento.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When touching the attributes you need to refresh the `Product Attributes` index.
When touching the products you need to refresh:

```
Product Attributes
Product Prices
Catalog URL Rewrites
Product Flat Data
Category Products
Catalog Search Index
Stock Status
Tag Aggregation Data
```

When touching the categories refresh:

```
Catalog URL Rewrites
Category Products
Category Flat Data
```

When updating cms pages and static blocks you don't need to refresh anything.

Comment: Marius, I just had some more doubts. Can you please help with it

Answer (score 0):

If you enable **update on save** mode for all indexes, magento will refresh only needed indexes. Here you have some description how to enable this mode http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-indexing .